An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/build'
Upgrading from Angular 13 to Angular 18
After Angular 18 is working
npm install @angular-architects/native-federation
ng add @angular-architects/native-federation --project=ptfe-angular-18-app --port=5511
npm start

ptfe-angular-18-app@18.0.0 start
ng serve  --port 5511

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/build'
Require stack:

C:\Travtronics\PropertyTech\ptfeapp-18.1.0\node_modules@angular-architects\native-federation\src\builders\build\builder.js
C:\Travtronics\PropertyTech\ptfeapp-18.1.0\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
See "C:\Users\sangu\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-M9HCtv\angular-errors.log" for further details.

angular.json file
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "ptfe-angular-18-app": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-architects/native-federation:build",
                    "options": {},
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "target": "ptfe-angular-18-app:esbuild:production"
                        },
                        "development": {
                            "target": "ptfe-angular-18-app:esbuild:development",
                            "dev": true
                        }
                    },
                    "defaultConfiguration": "production"
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-architects/native-federation:build",
                    "options": {
                        "target": "ptfe-angular-18-app:serve-original:development",
                        "rebuildDelay": 0,
                        "dev": true,
                        "port": 0
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "buildTarget": "ptfe-angular-18-app:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
                        "polyfills": [
                            "zone.js",
                            "zone.js/testing"
                        ],
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "scripts": [
                            "src/assets/vendor/pace/pace.min.js"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "node_modules/prismjs/plugins/toolbar/prism-toolbar.css",
                            "src/assets/css/animate.min.css",
                            "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
                            "node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/index.css",
                            "node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/assets/icons.css",
                            "src/assets/css/demo.css",
                            "src/assets/sass/core.scss",
                            "src/styles.css"
                        ],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/favicon.ico"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "esbuild": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
                    "options": {
                        "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
                            "@mattlewis92/dom-autoscroller",
                            "angular-calendar/date-adapters/date-fns",
                            "prismjs/plugins/copy-to-clipboard/prism-copy-to-clipboard",
                            "lodash",
                            "css-element-queries",
                            "sweetalert2",
                            "screenfull"
                        ],
                        "outputPath": {
                            "base": "dist/ptfe-angular-18-app"
                        },
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "polyfills": [
                            "zone.js",
                            "es-module-shims"
                        ],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/favicon.ico"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "node_modules/prismjs/plugins/toolbar/prism-toolbar.css",
                            "src/assets/css/animate.min.css",
                            "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
                            "node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/index.css",
                            "node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/assets/icons.css",
                            "src/assets/css/demo.css",
                            "src/assets/sass/core.scss",
                            "src/styles.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "src/assets/vendor/pace/pace.min.js"
                        ],
                        "extractLicenses": false,
                        "sourceMap": true,
                        "optimization": false,
                        "namedChunks": true,
                        "browser": "src/main.ts",
                        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                            "includePaths": [
                                "."
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                                }
                            ],
                            "aot": true,
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "dev": {
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve-original": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "buildTarget": "ptfe-angular-18-app:build",
                        "port": 5511
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "buildTarget": "ptfe-angular-18-app:esbuild:production"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "ptfe-angular-18-app-e2e": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "ptfe-angular-18-app:serve"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
            "prefix": "app"
        }
    },
    "cli": {
        "analytics": "9e472cbb-4d61-46ce-9a7c-5eae6a406034"
    }
}

package.json
{
  "name": "ptfe-angular-18-app",
  "version": "18.0.0",
  "license": "",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve  --port 5511",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-magic/ngx-gp-autocomplete": "^2.0.2",
    "@angular/animations": "18.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^18.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "18.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "18.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "18.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "18.2.1",
    "@angular/localize": "18.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "18.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "18.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "18.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "18.2.1",
    "@googlemaps/js-api-loader": "^1.16.8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^17.0.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^13.7.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.1.0",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.55.12",
    "acorn": "8.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.8",
    "core-js": "3.8.1",
    "date-fns": "2.16.1",
    "es-module-shims": "^1.5.12",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "hopscotch": "0.3.1",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^18.0.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^17.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^19.0.0",
    "prismjs": "1.22.0",
    "pug": "3.0.0",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "screenfull": "^6.0.2",
    "simplebar-angular": "^3.2.6",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.12.4",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "vite": "^5.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-architects/native-federation": "^18.1.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "18.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "18.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "18.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "18.2.1",
    "@types/core-js": "2.5.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.5.1",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.0",
    "postcss": "8.2.15",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.5.4",
    "sass": "~1.32.6",
    "ts-node": "8.6.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.2"
  }
}

angular 18  native ferdation install after re run app show error :An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/build'

You didn't mentioned what is the value for your jitMode in AngularWebpackPlugin in your webpack.config.js?
I had the similar problem and I solved it. Read these two links:
Angular 14: The injectable 'PlatformLocation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available
Migration from Node 14 to Node 18 - The injectable 'PlatformNavigation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler'
In second link there is an explanation provided in answer.
